# How do I setup Testling-CI with QUnit + QUnit-TAP?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, continuous-integration, qunit

### Problem

We are *trying* to setup ***Testling*** to run our **QUnit** (with ***QUnit-TAP***) tests following the "***Custom Libraries***" instructions: https://ci.testling.com/guide/custom_libraries

Our testling configuration (in package.json file) is:

```
"testling": {
  "html": "test.html",
  "browsers": [
    "ie/6..latest",
    "chrome/22..latest",
    "firefox/16..latest",
    "safari/latest",
    "opera/11.0..latest",
    "iphone/6",
    "ipad/6",
    "android-browser/latest"
  ]
}
```

*Full* **package.json**: http://git.io/vT3s7

and we setup the **WebHook** as per the **quick start** instructions:

[image: testling-web-hook-configuration]

But when we push to the repo the WebHook fails.
The ***payload*** is quite long. see: http://git.io/vT33D

Our tests work in the browser. See: https://learn-testling.herokuapp.com
(open devtools/console to) see the the ***Valid TAP output***:

[image: learn-testling-showing-valid-tap-output]

> *Any help much appreciated*!

### Background + Links

- We followed the instructions in the **quick start** guide: https://ci.testling.com/guide/quick_start
- But we are using QUnit in our project(s) so we followed the "***Custom Libraries***" instructions: https://ci.testling.com/guide/custom_libraries